# Id field in Model Django

Tags: django, django-models

I always get a primary column as Id in the Django model. Is there any possibility to change. For ex. for City table I want to have a Primary Key column as `city_id`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
city_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 26):

The answer is YES,

Something like this:

```
city_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Here, you are overriding the `id`. [Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.

Alternatively, You can always define a model property and use that . Example

```
class City(models.Model)
    #attributes
    @property
    def city_id(self):
        return self.id
```

and access it as `city.city_id` where you would normally do `city.id`

Comment: The second approach is so much better.

Comment: It may not be better if you want to migrate away from the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD later. Migrations away are still not implemented. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD

Answer (score 7):

By default, Django gives each model the following field:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This is an auto-incrementing primary key.

So for your case is:

```
city_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you can.

```py
city_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```